# Sharing a WebGL context with an iframe and/or window popups

Tags: javascript, iframe, electron, webgl

We're attempting to build an app that will allow embedded content (either DOM or iFrame) to be 'floated', ie. moved to a separate window via `window.open()`.

1. Can the WebGL render context be shared between the two windows? This would prevent the new window from having to rebuild the GPU context: texture uploads, shader compilation, etc.
2. Bonus question: can the context be shared between iframes?
3. Double bonus: for an Electron scenario, can the context be shared between render processes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can the WebGL render context be shared between the two windows? This would prevent the new window from having to rebuild the GPU context: texture uploads, shader compilation, etc.

A WebGL context can only be used with a single canvas so while you can use the context in another window (assuming it's a window that was opened by the same page) it can only render to the canvas it was originally associated with.

> Bonus question: can the context be shared between iframes?

Same as above

> Double bonus: for an Electron scenario, can the context be shared between render processes?

no, you can share across windows in the same process. You can not share across processes.

You can use canvas 2d to draw a WebGL canvas into a 2D canvas so you can use one canvas, render in that canvas, then copy it to iframes.

For an example see http://greggman.github.io/doodles/webgl_multiple_windows.html
 On the top left click `create new window`. Each new window is another view into the same scene. The windows, including the main window, are all rendered via using 2D canvases and drawImage

It might be possible that you can use an `OffscreenCanvas` and render to multiple canvases across iframes via [`transferToImageBitmap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/OffscreenCanvas/transferToImageBitmap).

Comment: For 1 and 2, are you sure about these affirmations? Why one window couldn't access the context from an other? Is there a special "same-origin-but-still-we-don't-let-you-access-that-object" special rule for the WebGLRenderingContext interface? Seems there isn't: https://jsfiddle.net/0dwxy4za/ And you can even move the renderer from one window to the other: https://jsfiddle.net/0dwxy4za/1/

Comment: Maybe I mis-understood the quesiton. You can't share a context across canvases therefore the fact that you can use the context across windows or iframes is mostly irrelevant. You'll still end up using the solution I suggested, render to one canvas, drawImage to the others.

Comment: They talked about content that would be "moved" to an other window. They didn't talk about another canvas. And no, my fiddle uses a single HTMLCanvasElement, with a single webgl context.

Comment: Ok. Updated the answer.